# Jquery autocomplete only working in one input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created three inputs for use with jquery autocomplete, but only the first works. The others dont display the values! How you can see here:

[image]

My inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="typef">
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="typef">
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="typef">
```

And my code:

```
$(function(){
$('.typef').autocomplete({
source: "/patients/list",
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( ".typef" ).val( ui.item.nachnahme + " " + ui.item.geburtsdatum ),
    $( ".typef2" ).val(ui.item.id );
    return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    return false;
  }

 })
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.vorname + " " + item.nachnahme + " " + item.geburtsdatum + " " + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
});
```

Comment: Could be because you use three times `name="FirstName"`. Give them a different name and see what happens.

Comment: No same error, i tried my code in fiddle and it worked! I think my css has the responsibility!

Comment: Could be. You can share your fiddle (or rather the CSS) if you keep having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks but i have another issue, like you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/466/ My code always adds the selected value to all three inputs! How can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('.typef').autocomplete({
        source: "/patients/list",
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).val( ui.item.nachnahme + " " + ui.item.geburtsdatum ),
                $( this ).val(ui.item.id );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            return false;
        }

    }).each(function(){
        $(this).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.vorname + " " + item.nachnahme + " " + item.geburtsdatum + " " + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JFdR8/)

Comment: Sorry but with this, the user cannot select an value! I hope you understand what i mean!

Comment: @EmSta I had changed the source for the fiddle, try now

Comment: Sorry but when the user clicks on the proposed values it wont be added to the input!

Answer (score 1):

try  assigning different id's to these field

and change `$('.typef').autocomplete({` to  `$('#id1, #id2, #id3').autocomplete({`

i updated fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/t8CnW/6/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.typef').val( ui.item.nachnahme + " " + ui.item.geburtsdatum)
```

to

```
$(ui).val( ui.item.nachnahme + " " + ui.item.geburtsdatum)
```

to solve the duplication issue.

[Here's your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8CnW/)

Comment: Sorry but with this, the value wont get selectet